# I want to view some items checked in listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I am beginner in android and i created a list view with check box, it is working but now i want to view some items as checked when it loaded. so please help me

here is my code

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int a=0;a<5;a++)
            {
                // I want to view item no 2 and 4 checked when it loaded  
                list.add("item"+a);
            }    
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
};
```

Comment: use base adapter and then use checks according to position in baseadapter

Comment: thanks I try to use adapter